# how to draw contents of widget in another widget in QT?

Tags: qt, qpainter

I want draw an existing widget A onto another widget B, (make A as the child of B may work, but here it's another story )

after search the internet , in qtcenter there is one [thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/8426-Draw-contents-of-widget-in-another-widget) said that:

```
 QPixmap w1Pix = QPixmap::grabWidget(w1); // can work
```

is there any other way to do that ?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with `grabWidget`? Why would you want to do something else?

Comment: So basicly what you're trying to achieve (explain another story)

Comment: grabWidget works for me , I am just curiosity if there is another way to achieve that :)

Comment: It depends if you only want to show it, or make it usable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of (don't know others) the alternatives is to use `QWidget`'s [`render`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#render) methods, which let you specify a `QPaintDevice` or a `QPainter` to render into, where into that painter you want to render, what region of the widget is to be painted, and [render flags](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#RenderFlag-enum). The flags let you specify whether you want children drawn or not, in particular.

This is a bit more flexible than `grabWidget`, but do read the docs, the device or the target's painter must be in specific states when you call these functions.